# Google is not showing the publisher. Added rel=publisher two months back

Tags: rel, google-authorship

I have added `rel=publisher` as:

```
<link href="https://plus.google.com/....." rel="publisher" />
```

Google plus page is working fine and showing it as validated. But after two months of time Google is not showing it in front of the brand name (when we search for the brand name).

Comment: You have added rel attribute to your website, have you linked your website to your G+ page?

Comment: yes ofcource I have.

Comment: What do you mean "Google is not showing it in from of the brand name"?

Comment: Any further update or clue on this guys?

Comment: Is it set up on Google+ as a business page (not a user page?). It will ignore it if not. x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google no longer displays sites differently in the search results when they have authorship or publisher markup.   From [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en):

> ### Authorship in web-search
>
> Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search.
>
> To learn about what markup you can use to improve search results, visit [rich snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170).